# how to make ProgressBar thicker

Tags: python, kivy

I need to make my ProgressBar thicker as in example, and i dont know how to change thickness of the ProgressBar. Changing height does not help at all, even when size_hint`s are None

[image]

there is a kv file:

```
WidgetsExample:

<WidgetsExample>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:(0.71, 0.71, 0.7,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "10dp"
    spacing: "10dp"
    Label:
        text: "You have not gambled for"
        size_hint: 1,.2
    ProgressBar:
        id: my_progress_bar
        max:100
        value: my_slider.value
        pos_hint: {"center_x" :.5}
        size_hint:.9,.1
    Slider:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: my_slider
        min:0
        max:100
        value:50
    Label:
        text: str(int(my_slider.value))
```

And there is my main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty



class WidgetsExample(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass



TheLabApp().run()
```

Comment: maybe it needs to change font size. Or change canvas size. Or maybe it has some margins which you could change. Or maybe you use some layout manager and you have to change its settings.

Comment: maybe create `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and run it - to test some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and use a custom `ProgressBar`, perhaps called `MyProgressBar` in your `kv` file:

```
<-MyProgressBar@ProgressBar>:
    thickness: 24
    color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        BorderImage:
            border: (12, 12, 12, 12)
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - 12
            size: self.width, 24
            source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/progressbar_background'
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - self.thickness/2
            size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, self.thickness
            radius: [self.thickness/4]
```

The above rule is based on the `kv` rule for the `ProgressBar` that is in the `style.kv` file installed with Kivy. The `-` at the start of the rule definition means that the default rule for `ProgressBar` should not be used for the `MyProgressBar`.

Then, in place of `ProgressBar` later in your `kv`, you can use `MyProgressBar`:

```
MyProgressBar:
    id: my_progress_bar
    thickness: 100
    color: [0, 1, 0, 1]
    max:100
    value: my_slider.value
    pos_hint: {"center_x" :.5}
    size_hint:.9,.2
```

To make the grey bar underneath the same size as the big progress bar, just modify the `kv` rule to replace the grey part (the `BorderImage`) with another `RoundedRectangle`:

```
<-MyProgressBar@ProgressBar>:
    thickness: 24
    color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - self.thickness/2
            size: self.width, self.thickness
            radius: [self.thickness/4]
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - self.thickness/2
            size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, self.thickness
            radius: [self.thickness/4]
```

Comment: How do i make the grey part of that progress bar as big as the green one?

Comment: See modified answer.